# Vue.js orderBy TotalPrice and Rate asc

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im trying to set the vue.js to orderBy a table of search result items, by TotalPrice or Rate. (clickable column header).

[image]

I tried vue.js documentatiom but the ascending ordering is not working.

My code:

```
    var SearchResultComponent = Vue.extend({
    template:
        '<div class="table-responsive">' +

            '<h3 class="selectedItemsHeader" style="margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;">{{ language.resultsItems }}</h3>' +

            '<table class="table">' +

                '<thead>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<th style="width:15%">' +
                            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" style="color:#333;" class="sort-btn companyrate" @click="sortBy = \'rate\'">{{ language.company }} <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>' +
                        '</th>' +
                        '<th style="width:30%">{{ language.service }}</th>' +
                        '<th style="width:10%">{{ language.servicePrice }}</th>' +
                        '<th style="width:10%">{{ language.discount }}</th>' +
                        '<th style="width:15%">{{ language.info }}</th>' +
                        '<th style="width:10%">' +
                            '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sort-btn totalVat" @click="sortBy = \'total\'">{{ language.totalVat }} <i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></a>' +
                        '</th>' +
                        '<th></th>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</thead>' +

                '<tbody v-if="items.length > 0">' +
                    '<tr v-for="item in items | orderBy itemByTotalPrice">' +
                        '<td class="clearfix">{{ item.companyName }}'+
                            '<span class="rate" v-if="item.companyRate"><span class="star"></span><span class="point">{{ item.companyRate }} / 5</span></span>'+
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td class="small-text item-name">{{{ getItemName(item) }}}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{ totalPriceNoDiscount(item) }} &euro;</td>' +
                        '<td>{{ totalPriceDiscount(item) }} &euro;</td>' +
                        '<td class="small-text">{{ item.companyNote || \' - \' }}</td>' +
                        '<td>{{ totalPrice(item) }} &euro;</td>' +
                        '<td>'+
                            '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" @click="select(item, $event)">{{ language.select }}</button>' +
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +


                '<tbody v-if="items.length == 0">' +
                    '<tr>' +
                        '<td colspan="7" style="font-size: 12pt;color: #777;padding-top: 60px;">{{ language.noResultsFound }}</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +

            '</table>' +

            '<h3 class="selectedItemsHeader" v-if="selectedItems.length > 0">{{ language.selectedItems }}</h3>' +

            '<table class="table selectedItems" v-if="selectedItems.length > 0">' +
                '<tbody>' +
                    '<tr v-for="item in selectedItems">' +
                        '<td style="width:15%">{{ item.selectedItem.companyName }}' +
                        '</td>' +
                        '<td style="width:30%" class="small-text item-name">{{{ getItemName(item.selectedItem) }}}</td>' +
                        '<td style="width:10%">{{ totalPriceNoDiscount(item.selectedItem) }} &euro;</td>' +
                        '<td style="width:10%">{{ totalPriceDiscount(item.selectedItem) || \'0.00\' }} &euro;</td>' +
                        '<td style="width:15%" class="small-text">{{ item.selectedItem.companyNote || \' - \' }}</td>' +
                        '<td style="width:10%">{{ totalPrice(item.selectedItem) }} &euro;</td>' +
                        '<td>'+
                            '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" @click="remove(item)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>' +
                        '</td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                '</tbody>' +
            '</table>' +
        '</div>',
    props: ['items','selectedItems','removeUrl'],
    data: function(){ return { sortBy: 'total' } },
    computed: {
        'language' : function() { return language; }
    },
    methods: {
        'select' : function(item, ev) {
            this.$dispatch('onCompanySelect', item);
            $(ev.target).attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
        },
        'remove' : function(item) {
            this.$dispatch('onSelectedItemRemove', {
                removeUrl: this.removeUrl,
                item: item
            });
        },
        'totalPriceNoDiscount' : function(item) {
            return item.priceNoDiscount.toFixed(2);
        },
        'totalPriceDiscount' : function(item) {
            return (item.priceNoDiscount - this.totalPrice(item)).toFixed(2);
        },
        'totalPrice' : function(item) {
            return item.extraServicesPriceVat ? (item.priceVat + item.extraServicesPriceVat).toFixed(2) : item.priceVat.toFixed(2);
        },
        'itemByTotalPrice' : function(a, b) {
            if(this.sortBy == 'total') {
                $('a.companyrate').css('color', '#333');
                $('a.totalVat').css('color', '#337ab7');
                return this.totalPrice(a) > this.totalPrice(b);
            } else if(this.sortBy == 'rate') {
                $('a.totalVat').css('color', '#333');
                $('a.companyrate').css('color', '#337ab7');
                return a.companyRate < b.companyRate;
            }
        }
    }

});
```

Any suggestions ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Pretty sure you want a sort-comparison function for `itemByTotalPrice`. You've got a boolean. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: `itemByTotalPrice` is a function

Comment: It's a function. It is not a sort-comparison function, which returns a negative value to indicate less-than and a positive value to indicate greater-than. It returns a boolean.

Comment: @RoyJ ok. So. When u try to return a sort() function, nothing is working. How do you suggest on doing that ? The `iTemByTotalPrice` gets a pair of totalPrice items to compare them and then returns them. Not the whole `totalPrice` objects of `items`